# installing wildfly error: services failed

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am very new to wildfly and frameworks like that. I followed a tutorial https://tomylab.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/how-to-install-wildfly-on-windows/ 
but when I applied

```
C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.bat
```

I get the following error. I don't understand what is going on. I tried looking up this error online, but the results were either different or too confusing. How do I fix this?

```
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:142)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:190)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpListenerService.startListening(HttpListenerService.java:126)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:138)
    13:28:14,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
    13:28:14,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    13:28:15,900 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    13:28:15,901 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    13:28:15,918 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("http-listener" => "default")
    ]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.listener.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
    13:28:15,924 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.ws.config"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
    13:28:15,927 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "ejb3")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => [
        "jboss.ejb.default-local-ejb-receiver-service",
        "jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.default",
        "jboss.ejb3.localEjbReceiver.value"
    ],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
    13:28:15,931 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "remote")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.connector is missing [jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector]"]}
    13:28:16,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector]
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener

    13:28:16,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    13:28:16,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    13:28:16,869 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 69357ms - Started 256 of 551 services (6 services failed or missing dependencies, 371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: You have some other application running at port 8080, stop it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting below exception while starting the server.

```
 - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.listener.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
13:28:15,924 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.ws.config"],
"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
```

It means that the port/address you are trying to use is already in use by some other application or service.

You will have either stop that application or service or change the port used by the wildfly.

You can start wildfly using port offset option also.